# How to change one table with multiple rows to a table with one row and multiple columns in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table with some specs as rows

```
product_id  |   spec      |   value   |
------------+-------------+-----------+
  prod-1    |   speed     |    30     |
  prod-1    |   weight    |    20     |
  prod-1    |   power     |    500    |
  prod-1    |   autonomy  |    20     |
```

and i want to create a query or function that returns this as

```
product_id   | speed  | weight  | power | autonomy |
-------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+
  prod-1     |  30    |    20   |  500  |    20    |
```

for better manipulation in front end.

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `crosstab` function from the extension [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tablefunc.html) to convert rows into columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
 'SELECT product_id, spec, value FROM specs' 
) AS ct(product_id int, speed int,  weight int, power int, autonomy int);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0e9f3e9351da53916a94290faece71ed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres look slike:

```
select product_id,
       max(value) filter (where spec = 'weight') as weight,
       max(value) filter (where spec = 'speed') as speed,
       max(value) filter (where spec = 'power') as power,
       max(value) filter (where spec = 'autonomy') as autonomy
from specs s
group by product_id;
```